# slicing tuples backwards - how to handle getting the first element?

Tags: python

Let's say I want elements 1-3 of a tuple, backwards:

```
x = (0,1,2,3,4)
x[1:4]
```

Returns `(1,2,3)`

And

```
x[3:0:-1]
```

Returns `(3,2,1)`

But what if I want elements 0-2?

I can do `x[2::-1]` to get the correct answer of `(2,1,0)` but `x[2:0:-1]` returns `(2,1)` and `x[2:-1:-1]` returns `()`.

Is there a way to slice to the last item without using a `if` statement if I am slicing at unknown intervals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One slightly inefficient way:

```
x[0:3][::-1]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
tuple(reversed(x[0:3]))
```

I'm not sure offhand how well the unnecessary intermediate tuple gets optimized away.

Comment: It's unlikely to be optimized away.  It's also unlikely to matter.  +1 for clever solution.

Comment: For the given small example, I'm getting that `x[2::-1]` takes about 65% as much time as than `x[0:3][::-1]`.

Comment: This works. Thanks @RogerFan for testing the efficiency. Hopefully someone has something better, but at this point I am betting that this is the best choice besides a if statement.

Comment: @RogerFan:  So basically it's negligible.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Well, I think it might scale up a bit with larger arrays. I just tested it extracting a 5000-length tuple and it goes down to about 50% as much time. But in general I think that's true.

Comment: Interestingly, I just tried timing this method vs. the method in the comments of another post. The version with the embedded `if` statement utilizing `None` is slower than this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `None` in place of the empty element:

```
x[2:None:-1]
```

Comment: That doesn't help the fact that you have to separately test for a 0 though. It just changes what goes in the if condition.

Comment: @RogerFan:  `x[2:None if whatever else dx:-1]`

Comment: @RogerFan I didn't make the rules, sorry. And it can still be useful if you're using a variable to indicate the endpoints.

Comment: Doesn't quite seem to fit exactly what the OP is looking for but it's still good to know.

Answer (score 0):

with `x[-n:]`  you can get the last `n` index and with `[::-1]` you can inverse it !

```
>>> x[-2:][::-1]
(4, 3)
>>>
```

Comment: OP discusses that in the question and points out that that requires detecting the 0 index for the first desired element as a special case - I think the OP is looking for a generic answer for getting the reversed tuple elements from m to n for any valid m and n without checking whether m==0.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps merge a "reverse-sentinel" tuple with your original tuple, and subscript that:

```
>>> x = (0, 1, 2, 3)
>>> y = (0,)
```

Then:

```
>>> (y + x)[3:0:-1]
(2, 1, 0)
>>> (y + x)[2:0:-1]
(1, 0)
```

Not as fast as Peter DeGlopper's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26067026/19410), though:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

x = tuple(range(0,int(1e6)))
y = (0,)

start_time = time.time()
a = (y+x)[3:0:-1]
print("tuple add --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
b = x[0:3][::-1]
print("tuple rev --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Not even close, really:

```
$ ./test61.py
tuple add --- 0.0153260231018 seconds ---
tuple rev --- 6.19888305664e-06 seconds ---
```